Microsoft Graph API insufficient privileges with reset password
I'm trying to reset a user's password using the Microsoft Graph API, but I keep getting the following error:

Authorization_RequestDenied
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

What I've tried:

I've checked permissions in Azure: all required user-related permissions (User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, etc.) are configured as application permissions and have been granted by an administrator

I've confirmed that the token has the correct scopes: I've parsed the access token using the jwt.ms tool and it shows the expected permissions

I've used an account with administrative privileges; the account making the call has the necessary privileges to manage users in the directory

Permission propagation: the permissions were granted more than 24 hours ago, so propagation time shouldn't be the issue


Additional context

The application is registered correctly with Azure and permissions have been granted for the entire organization
The API is being called as the application and not as a delegated user
All administrative permissions are configured for the application
Other requests such as creating users, deleting them, etc. work correctly, the problem is only with resetting the password

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Have you check this docs? As mentioned in the documentation, currently reset password is only supported with delegated permissions scope.
Others also said, link


As mentioned in the link, you can assign a directory role to the application that enables this scenario.
